# I don't know where my jupyter is getting my installed modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, package

I'm trying to import the library fbprophet and it needs some libraries such as pandas, matplotlib, numpy, cython and pystan. I'm using an Azure HDInsight machine with Spark and I'm connecting to it via ssh. I'm importing all the above libraries and apparently, they are all already installed, but when I try to import the packages in my Jupyter Notebook it doesn't find it. These are some data:

By executing this code

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)

print(sys.version)

print(sys.path)
```

I obtained these results:

```
/usr/bin/anaconda/bin/python

2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

['/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1588377332162_0008/container_1588377332162_0008_01_000001/tmp', 

u'/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1588377332162_0008/spark-696b8b12-f622-42b6-a98c-fffb3fe98699/userFiles-3aa153a1-2c0e-4a2c-bece-a91a7864d308', 

'/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python', '/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip', 

'/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1588377332162_0008/container_1588377332162_0008_01_000001/pyspark.zip', 

'/mnt/resource/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1588377332162_0008/container_1588377332162_0008_01_000001/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip', '/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python27.zip', 

'/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7', '/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 

'/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 

'/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.6-py2.7.egg', 

'/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg', 

'/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/var/lib/.jupyter/jupyterazure']
```

I have just checked that my packages are being installed in the path specified by this line '/usr/bin/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages' in the chunk of code above, but my jupyter seems like if it wasn't getting them from there although the path is pointing to the folder that contains them. Is there any specific code to see the path that my jupyter notebook is using to import packages? I've used this one 'print(sys.path)' but I'm not sure if this code shows that information. If it does, then I don't know why my jupyter notebook is not getting those packages that are already installed there.

If you need extra information do not hesitate to ask. I need help but I don't know what extra data I can provide you to help me.

Comment: Can you add the output of `print(sys.executable)` when executed in jupyter notebook?

Comment: this is the output: /usr/bin/anaconda/bin/python